# Unexpected output for subtrees during index-based implemenation of a kd-tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, kdtree

I'm trying to implement an efficient [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) which uses indexes rather than storing the points in a structure for its subtrees.
During the creation of its left and right subtrees, it connects to the desired point but won't connect to other desired points. For some data, the results won't make any sense. In the current implementation, let's take a minimum example of three points
(5, 4), (9, 6), (7, 2). The tree currently builts something like this:

```
#
#          (9, 6)[1]
#           /  \
#          /    B
#         /
#     (7,2)[2]  (5,4)[0]
#       /  \
#       B  B
```

While it should have been like this:

```
#
#          (7,2)[2]
#           /  \
#          /    \
#         /      \
#     (5,4)[0]  (9,6)[1]
#       /  \      / \
#       B  B     B   B
```

where `B` is blank/null value and the indexes are given in the square brackets(`[]`). Adding more data makes gives more absurd tree formations.

For finding the median value, I'm using [Quickselect method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). Code is similar to the pseudo-code given there.

The entire code is given [here](https://gitlab.com/sachinkumarsingh092/gnuastro-matching-fits-nohealpix/-/blob/mohammad/kdtree.c).

The functions of concern are `kdtree_median_find` and `kdtree_fill_subtrees`. Can someone please suggest where am I going logically wrong with this?

Please ask if anything is unclear in the comments. I'll try to explain it in further details:-)